# I would like links to respond on mouse hover, not on empty space

Tags: css, tumblr

When I separate the bottom links (music, contact, archive) with padding, they are highlighted even when the mouse moves over the empty space that divides them. I would like the mouse to react only to the links that it hovers over and ignore the empty space, however I'm uncertain how to do it on this platform. I can post the full code for the blog if needed.

```css
/*header*/

header {
    width:{select:post width}px;
    margin:140px auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: inconsolata;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: none-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;    
}

.ico {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:35px;
}

.ico img { /*icon*/
    margin:0 auto;    
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:100%;
    -webkit-border-radius:100%;
    -moz-border-radius:100%;
}

.about {
    position:relative;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}

.desc {
    padding:25px 0;
    opacity:0;
}

.dnav {margin-top:10px;
       margin-bottom: 110px;
}

.dnav a {
    font-family: inconsolata; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    letter-spacing:3px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    display:inline-block;
    
    
}

.dnav a:after {
    content:'';
    color:{color:link}!important;    
    padding-left:15px;
}

.dnav a:hover::after {color:{color:link}!important;}

.dnav a:last-of-type::after {display:none;}


nav {
    font-family: inconsolata; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    letter-spacing:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
}

nav a {margin:0 0px;}

#blogt {
    
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight:bold;
        /*color:{color:title};*/ 
    
}
```

```html
<body>

<header>
{block:ifIconImage}<a href="/" class="ico"><img src="{image:Icon}"></a>{/block:ifIconImage}
    <nav>{block:ifAskTitle}<a href="/ask">{text:ask title}</a>{/block:ifAskTitle}{block:ifProfileTitle}<a class="pro">{text:profile title}</a>{/block:ifProfileTitle}<a id="blogt" href="/">{Title}</a>{block:ifArchiveTitle}<a href="/archive">{text:archive title}</a>{/block:ifArchiveTitle}</nav>
    <div class="about"><div class="desc">{Description}</div></div>
    
    <div class="dnav">{block:ifLink1}<a href="{text:Link 1 URL}">{text:Link 1}</a>{/block:ifLink1}{block:ifLink2}<a href="{text:Link 2 URL}">{text:Link 2}</a>{/block:ifLink2}{block:ifLink3}<a href="{text:Link 3 URL}">{text:Link 3}</a>{/block:ifLink3}</div>
    </div></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, padding is part of the element, so hovering over it will trigger the mouseOver event.

Try using margins instead.

Answer (score 1):

The ".dnav a:after" css selector is extending the text.

You can add margin to the "a" element itself with the ".dnav a" selector, remove the ".dnav a:after" selector with it's properties and it should work.

Like this:

Delete that:

```
.dnav a:after {
    content:'';
    color:{color:link}!important;    
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

Change that (by just adding margin):

```
.dnav a {
    font-family: inconsolata; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    letter-spacing:3px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what was needed. Thank you.

Comment: If this solved your problem click the gray check mark to the left. It will show others that your problem has been solved.